# Populating domain entities from database

Tags: c#, entity-framework, domain-driven-design, lazy-loading, eager-loading

I have many things like this in my code (this is just one simple example):

```
var invoice = context.Invoices
                     .ForId(invoiceId)
                     .Include(i => i.Payments)
                     .Include(i => i.OrderLines)
                     .First();
```

And `Invoice` has field `UnpaidAmount` caclulated as

```
public double UnpaidAmount
{
    get
    {
        return OrderLines.Sum(ol => ol.Amount) -
               Payments.Sum(p => p.Amount);
    }
}
```

Now, what happens often in the project is that if someone needs to modify `UnpaidAmount` logic to this for instance:

```
return OrderLines.Sum(ol => ol.Amount) -
       Payments.Sum(p => p.Amount) -
       CreditNotes.Sum(cn => cn.Amount);
```

Then they would need to find everywhere in project where `UnpaidAmount` is used and add `CreditNotes` to `Include` when fetching `Invoice`. People often forget that and, in this case, `Sum` on `CreditNotes` actually gets called on an empty collection, instead on one fetched from database.

This becomes really buggy and hard to maintain through project.

The alternative is to either lose `LazyLoading` so we dont have to think about includes anywhere but this can lead to performance problems which might not be detected during the develpoment but later in production when number of records fetched gets larger.

Or to have one method which fetches `Invoice` object with all of its navigation properties + recursively doing it for navigation properties deeper in the object graph. But that would be overkill because many things which are not needed would be fetched every time.

I assume it is trade off which I will have to make, but I just need advice from people who faced with this kind of problem on larger projects, what solution do you think is most maintainable for long run?

Answer (score 1):

> Then they would need to find everywhere in project where UnpaidAmount is used and add CreditNotes to Include when fetching Invoice.

Why does this responsibility live in more than one place?

> The alternative is to either lose LazyLoading so we dont have to think about includes anywhere but this can lead to performance problems which might not be detected during the develpoment but later in production when number of records fetched gets larger.
>
> Or to have one method which fetches Invoice object with all of its navigation properties + recursively doing it for navigation properties deeper in the object graph. But that would be overkill because many things which are not needed would be fetched every time.

What I think you are looking for is the Repository Pattern.

The basic idea:

You have one or more [role interfaces](https://martinfowler.com/bliki/RoleInterface.html) that consumers can use to describe how they are going to use the Invoice (or alternatively, which *view* of the invoice satisfies their needs).

You provide implementations of those roles that share a common understanding of how the invoice data is stored.  This means that when you introduce CreditNotes into the model, there's only one place that needs to change.

You use your plumbing (dependency injection, or whatever) to ensure that the correct implementation is provided for each role.

In short, you create an explicit contract between the consumers and the suppliers; the consumers describe what they need, the suppliers have freedom of choice in how they meet that need.

Udi Dahan wrote a few posts related to this idea, back in the day.

- [Better Domain Driven Design Implementation](http://udidahan.com/2007/03/06/better-domain-driven-design-implementation/)
- [Query Objects vs Methods on a Repository](http://udidahan.com/2007/03/28/query-objects-vs-methods-on-a-repository/)
- [Fetching Strategy Design](http://udidahan.com/2007/04/23/fetching-strategy-design/)
- [Intentions and Interfaces](https://www.slideshare.net/deimos/udi-dahan-intentions-and-interfaces)

Answer (score 0):

Can offer to introduce some kind of Store, called, for example, Invoices. It will get DbContext in constructor, and provide all the methods you have to fetch and save invoices. So, you will have only one place to write and modify query.

```
class Invoices
{
    public Invoices(DbContext dbContext){....}

    public Invoice GetInvoiceById(int invoiceId)
    {
        return this.dbContext.Invoices
            .ForId(invoiceId)
            .Include(i => i.Payments)
            .Include(i => i.OrderLines)
            .FirstOrDefault();
    }
...
```